# When copying a work item in TFS can i control the link created between the items?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

When I copy a work item in TFS *`(a bug for example)`*, the link between the parent work item and the newly created item is always set to `related`. 
I want to change the default link type created when copying since I want to use a `custom link` type i created.I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot control the link type when copying a work item.

However you can delete the `related` links, then add them again with selecting other link types (custom link type in your scenario) with TFS API.

Please refer to below articles for more information.

- [TFS API Cloning Work Items with Children](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1118805/TFS-API-Cloning-Work-Items-with-Children)
- [Create Link Between Work Item (Parent, Child etc…)](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2010/02/27/tfs-api-part-22-create-link-between-work-item-parent-child-etc/)
- [Creating a linked Workitem via the TFS API](http://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2013/01/17/Creating-a-linked-Workitem-via-the-TFS-API.aspx)